# AngularJS and nesting Directives

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive that roughly represents a table.  Also I want to create a directive that defines the columns in that table.  The table directive ng-repeats on the tr and displays the custom columns per row.

I'm pretty new to angular.  Any help would be appreciated, here is the code and jsfiddle link.

As you can see from the fiddle this doesn't work yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/P6Nq4/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    Table of People:
    <my-table>
        <my-td my-data-name='Name'></my-td>
        <my-td my-data-name='Description'></my-td>
    </my-table>
    <button>done</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController',function($scope){
    $scope.items = [{Name: 'John', Description: 'Awesome'},
                    {Name: 'Pat', Description: 'Ambiguous'}];
})
.directive('myTable', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        },
        transclude:true,
        template: '<table><tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-transclude>'
                    +'<td>static column at the end</td></tr></table>'
    };
}).directive('myTd', function(){
    return {
        link: function (scope,element,attrs){
            scope.data = attrs.myDataName;
        },
        template: '<td><input ngModel="eval(\'item.\' + data)" /></td>'
    }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you need to change:

1. `restrict` property of the directive definition object. By default, directives are restricted to being html attributes - if you want to use an element (like you have), you need to set `restrict` to include an `E`. [Link to docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
2. You had `ngModel="eval(\'item.\' + data)"`. First issue with this is that in html, angular uses a hyphenated form, and not camelCase, so change `ngModel` to `ng-model`. Secondly, the `ng-model` attribute is automatically evaluated against the scope, so you don't need to use eval. The better approach is to use javascript's bracket notation to access the property. So your `ng-model` binding becomes:
3. Finally, if you are re-using a directive, you almost always want to create a new scope, if not an isolate scope, otherwise scopes can interfere with eachother. In your case, the data from the second column overwrites the first column. To fix this, force the creation of a new scope with `scope: true`

You can see all of the changes in [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Nq4/1/). I would suggest commenting out the `scope` line and making sure you understand what happens if you don't have separate scopes, as it's a little bit subtle.

**EDIT**

Regarding your static column, I think it makes more sense (and it's much simpler) if you include your static column as static html. So instead of putting it in your `my-table` template, you add it like so:

```
<my-table>
    <my-td my-data-name='Name'></my-td>
    <my-td my-data-name='Description'></my-td>
    <td>static column</td>
</my-table>
```

I think this is simpler, and also keeps the html semantic, and representative of what it will be compiled into. [This shows it working](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Nq4/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I knew about restrict but I forgot to add it to the example.  Why do you include both in the restrict and not just E?  Just so that it could be used either way?  the ng-model was a simple error on my part as well, but yes, I was wondering the best way to access a property from an object with its string name.

The last thing that I have is how do I include that static column in the main directive?  Transclude seems to wipe out everything inside wherever it is declared.

Comment: Yes, `EA` is a habit from a tutorial I learned on - it can be used either way. I will take a look at transclude now - I've never used it myself.

Comment: See my edit - I'd keep static columns as static html, not template strings.